# How to monitor the scroll behavior with google analytics in all SharePoint pages?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using google analitics. I have added some javascript inside my masterpage. Now I would like to also monitor the scroll behavior of the visitors. Is there someone who knows how to do that in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below opensource plugin which can help with tracking scroll behaviour.
http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/

Note: Please use one of the dimension to store the scroll percentage.

Comment: Is this solution also possible without Google Tag Manager? I try the solution of you, but it registers only the baseline in my stats. I do not see the 25, 50, 75 and 100 % labels.

Comment: No, GTM is not needed.